# Problema com estilização da tabela usando BootGrid()

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, asp.net-mvc

Quando eu renderizo essa *table* dentro de um *Modal* e uso a função `BootGrid()`, ela não consegue carregar todos os estilos necessários, fazendo com que os botões de navegação por exemplo não sejam devidamente estilizados.

Código da tabela que a requisição retorna:

```js
<table class="table table-condensed table-striped bootgrid-table" id="bootgrid-command">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                <div class="text-right">Ações</div>
            </th>
            <th data-column-id="id" data-type="numeric">Código</th>
            @for (int i = 0; i < Model.HeaderColumns.Length; i++)
            {
                <th data-column-id="@Model.DisplayColumns[i]" data-type="text">@Model.HeaderColumns[i]</th>
            }
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.DataTable.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                @for (int f = 0; f < Model.DisplayColumns.Length; f++)
                {
                    <td>@Model.DataTable.Rows[i][Model.DisplayColumns[f]]</td>
                }
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Código do modal:

```js
@model Angle.Models.PopupSelecaoPadraoViewModel

<script>
    function ReloadModalInfo(componenteName) {
        $.post('@Url.Action("GridView", "Forms")', { token: $('#' + componenteName + '_token').val() }, function (data) {
            $('#abrirModal').click()
            $('#modalContent').html('')
            $('#modalContent').html(data)
            setTimeout(function () {

                $('#bootgrid-command').bootgrid({
                rowSelect: true,
                selection: true,
                rowCount: 5,
                labels: {
                    noResults: "where are my results"
                }
                });

            }, 0)
            
        })
    }
</script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/vendor/jquery-bootgrid/dist/jquery.bootgrid.css">

<script src="@Scripts.Url("~/Vendor/jquery-bootgrid/dist/jquery.bootgrid.js")"></script>
<script src="@Scripts.Url("~/Vendor/jquery-bootgrid/dist/jquery.bootgrid.fa.js")"></script>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body" id="modalContent">
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<button type="button" style="display: none" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" id="abrirModal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Abrir janela Modal</button>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de saber o que eu devo fazer para carregar corretamente os estilos dentro de um modal?

Comment: Quando você carrega seus estilos no header da pág, ele se aplica a todos os seus elementos... Nesse caso ele se aplica tanto dentro como fora do modal... 
Quando você inspeciona a página, no console é apresentado algum erro?

Comment: Nenhum erro é apresentado amigo.

Comment: Então... Tem algo conflitando com o seu script e você vai ter que passar um pente fino para entender, pois o jQuery Bootgrid já puxa os estilos do bootstrap... :/